# Office 365 API for SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, office365

I am very much new to Office 365 API's. I am using Microsoft.Office365.SharePoint and Microsoft.Office365.OAuth libraries to access the documents in Office 365 sharepoint site.

I am able to aunthenticate (using SiteApiSample.cs this is the sample provided by MSDN for Office 365 API's) to office 365. I am able to get the file name from sharepoint by using the below code.

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<IFileSystemItem>> GetDefaultDocumentFiles()
        {
            var client = await EnsureClientCreated();
            client.Context.IgnoreMissingProperties = true;    

            // Obtain files in default SharePoint folder

            var filesResults = await client.Files.ExecuteAsync();
            var files = filesResults.CurrentPage.OrderBy(e => e.Id);
            return files;
        }
```

Now my intention is that, I would need to get the file content / folder content to a byte array. I have tried several ways, but did not worked. If some one has working sample with this request you to please share. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation with anything Office 365 development is to start at http://dev.office.com/, plenty of documentation, code samples, videos and training there.

The files API is documented here (following the documentation link) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605900(v=office.15).aspx.

You can get the file contents using in the REST API:

```
/_api/files(<file_path>)/download
```

or you can use the Class Libraries in the Visual Studio project like your sample above:

```
public static async Task<Stream> GetFileContent(string strFileId)
{
    var file = (IFileFetcher)(await _spFilesClient.Files.GetById(strFileId).ToFile().ExecuteAsync());

    var streamFileContent = await file.DownloadAsync();

    streamFileContent.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

    return streamFileContent;
}
```

To get the actual file using the files API there are some great samples by someone who wrote the tools in the visual studio team, @chakkaradeep. http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/office-365-api-my-files-crud-sample-code/